# Media Source Extensions appendBuffer of WebM stream in random order

Tags: webm, media-source

I am trying to achieve video downloading in parallel from multiple sources. However MSE appendBuffer method always fails when not following sequence order of video file.

I would like to append parts in random order and play video "as soon as possible".
I was exploring SourceBuffer mode property as well as timestampOffset. None of those were helpful.

I am wondering if source webm file i have could be in "not supported format" for such a task (sequential approach works fine).

[source video file](http://lukyer.cz/stackoverflow/repaired_original.webm)

Thank you for any advices.

**UPDATE:**
I tried to analyse well known [example video file](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/test.webm) and i figured out that it is possible to append parts of it out of order. Seems like it is necessary to follow **Cluster byte ranges**:

```
<Cluster type="list" offset="4357">
  <Timecode type="uint" value="0"/>
  <SimpleBlock type="binary" size="7723" trackNum="1" timecode="0" presentationTimecode="0" flags="80"/>
  <SimpleBlock type="binary" size="5" trackNum="2" timecode="0" presentationTimecode="0" flags="80"/>
  ...
</Cluster>
<Cluster type="list" offset="16187">
  <Timecode type="uint" value="385"/>
  <SimpleBlock type="binary" size="5" trackNum="2" timecode="0" presentationTimecode="385" flags="80"/>
  <SimpleBlock type="binary" size="4968" trackNum="1" timecode="13" presentationTimecode="398" flags="80"/>
  ...
</Cluster>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging into webm format specification, compiling libwebm tools and studying DASH i **finally figured out how to make MSE appendBuffer working in any order!**

1. ffmpeg -i result.webm -g 10 -c:v libvpx resultClusters.webm (you can also use libvpx-vp9)
2. mkvmuxer_sample  -i resultClusters.webm -o resultRepaired.webm
3. mse_json_manifest resultRepaired.webm >> manifest.json

You will get on stdout something like:

```
{
  "type": "video/webm; codecs=\"vp8\"",
  "duration": 27771.000000,
  "init": { "offset": 0, "size": 258},
  "media": [
    { "offset": 258, "size": 54761, "timecode": 0.000000 },
    { "offset": 55019, "size": 166431, "timecode": 2.048000 },
    { "offset": 221450, "size": 49258, "timecode": 4.130000 },
    { "offset": 270708, "size": 29677, "timecode": 6.148000 },
    { "offset": 300385, "size": 219929, "timecode": 8.232000 },
    { "offset": 520314, "size": 25132, "timecode": 10.335000 },
    { "offset": 545446, "size": 180777, "timecode": 12.440000 },
    { "offset": 726223, "size": 76107, "timecode": 14.471000 },
    { "offset": 802330, "size": 376557, "timecode": 14.794000 },
    { "offset": 1178887, "size": 247138, "timecode": 16.877000 },
    { "offset": 1426025, "size": 78468, "timecode": 18.915000 },
    { "offset": 1504493, "size": 25614, "timecode": 20.991000 },
    { "offset": 1530107, "size": 368277, "timecode": 23.093000 },
    { "offset": 1898384, "size": 382847, "timecode": 25.097000 },
    { "offset": 2281231, "size": 10808, "timecode": 27.135000 }
  ]
}
```

Now all you have to do is firstly load metadata `xhr.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=0-257");` and then in **ANY ORDER** all other segments. E.g. second segment range is `55019-221449` bytes.

Explanation:

The most important thing is *ffmpeg* reencoding with **group of frames** set to the size of cluster you would like to have. In this example i choose  pretty low threshold (each 10 frames) but you can choose higher **causing fewer clusters are generated** (less items in "media" array).

After that you have to fix *cues* in the classic way (using *sample_muxer* from *libwebm*) and you are ready to go.

Tested on: Chrome 51, Firefox 47.